# Qual a vantagem de usar OSGI?

Tags: java, java-ee

Qual a vantagem de utilizar o OSGI para separar os módulos do projeto?

Como ficaria as transações em operações entre os módulos, e os relacionamentos entre as entidades de modulo diferentes?